# How to disable pdf plug-in icons from being displayed when using atreal.richfile.preview in <embed> tag in Plone 4.1

Tags: javascript, plone, adobe-reader

I am using atreal.richfile.preview in Plone 4.1. For pdf preview how do I disable the icons in the  tag for the plug-in which displays the icons for zoom + - print or save the pdf file. The embed tag is as follows in the custom : site/portal_view_customizations/atreal.richfile.preview.interfaces.ipreview-atreal.richfile.preview.viewlet

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%"
         tal:condition="ispdf"
         tal:attributes="src string:${here/absolute_url}" 
         draggable="false" onselectstart="false"  />
```

Basically which javascript is displaying these icons which needs to be disabled? how can this be achieved? Which javascript needs to be disabled? Please guide.
These icons are visible on a mouseover event at the right bottom corner of the preview window

Answer (score 0):

Change

`tal:attributes="src string:${here/absolute_url}"`

To

`tal:attributes="src string:${here/absolute_url}#toolbar=0"`

Comment: this did not help. Thx for trying. I am desparately looking out for the solution

Comment: worked on my testsite. btw: in case you want to inhibit downloads, disableling the buttons, doesn't suffice.

Comment: I hv overridden the download too.

Comment: BTW @Ida Ebkes which browser and what version have you used? Kindly revert

Comment: Firefox 15.01. But the issue concerns more Adobe here. I'd say go for wc.pageturner instead. It's open source, written by top-plonistas and you're not relying on (proprietary) browser add-ons.

Comment: tried that too but the author suggested collective.documentviewer and that is not getting installed properly on my linux debian. There is an option to control 'enable print' which I guessed I could use but it is not installing. Don't know how to proceed. I desparately need to incorporate this option urgently. :(